# Regex to check space after individual single quote or individual double quote

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I have to check for individual single or double quotes using regex if there are no alphabets or numbers in string.

For example:

```
Max's --> is valid
' --> Invalid
" --> Invalid
```

So I used a regex

```
^(?=.*[\\w\\d]).+
```

This works pretty much fine except it also allows

```
Max" M--> Here there is space after quote which is supposed to be invalid
While Max"M M --> should be valid same goes for single quote
```

What changes should I do to achieve that condition for validation ?

Example :

There should be at least one alphabet or a numeric character, only special characters are not allowed.
If input string is:

```
' --> Is invalid
" --> Is invalid
# --> Is invalid
^ --> Is invalid
and so on...
```

but if the input string is

```
Max's pc --> Valid
1's --> Valid
Max"s pc --> Valid
1"s --> Valid
```

but again if it is

```
Max' --> Invalid as the word ends with '
Max" --> Invalid as the word ends with "
```

Here I do not want my word to end with ' or " or any other special character but yes commas, semicolons or full stops are allowed.

Please mention if any further clarification is required. Thanks :)

Comment: Your regex and requirements are totally different. What are you really trying to do? BTW, `[\w\d]` = `\w`.

Comment: Please post some examples of what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: What mean the letter `M` in examples ?

Comment: @kip M is just some letter it could also be a word, consider the input as a sentence but there should not be any word in this sentence ending with ' or " or some other special character other than commas, semicolons or full stops.

I updated also my question as suggested  :)

Comment: How about valid words that really end with `'` like `for goodness' sake`?

Comment: No these are exceptional cases and I would like to ignore such cases, considering for goodness' sake as invalid would do for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but this maybe can work:

```js
var text = [
    "'",
    '"',
    '#',
    '^',
    "Max's pc",
    "1's",
    'Max"s pc',
    '1"s',
    "Max'",
    'Max"',
    'Max" M'
];

var expr = /([^\s\w\d]+)(?=[\w\d]+)/;

text.map(function(v) {
   console.log(v, expr.test(v)); 
});
```

**EDIT**

Added more examples

```js
var text = [
    "Max's",
    'Max"s',
    "Max' s",
    'Max" s',
];

var expr = /([^\s\w\d]+)(?=[\w\d]+)/;

text.map(function(v) {
   console.log(v, expr.test(v)); 
});
```

Comment: Hey sorry, I should've been more specific I cannot actually put Max and such static things, I was just giving example, of what type of input is valid and what type is not.

Comment: I understand but if you test the expression with your real values is it useful or not? If isn't useful I can delete my answer error

Comment: oh extremely sorry I actually didn't check it I'll let you know.

Comment: No it is not what I want actually Max's should be valid but Max' s should not be valid, look at it this way after ' or " there should not be any space or end of line, there should be some character after that

Comment: Check the answer again and run the code snippet in **EDIT** section, show the correct expect boolean no?

Comment: Hii, that works I was putting regex as string so this is what I was writing "/([^\\s\\w\\d]+)(?=[\\w\\d]+)/", which did not work for me, so I did not use it as a string and this worked just fine, could you tell me if those escape characters messed with your regex for some reason?

Comment: I think that you need read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp), in section **Metacharacters** is a really useful explanation

Answer (score 1):

try this regex according to your requirement.
**[a-zA-Z0-9]['"][\S]**

var regex = /[a-zA-Z0-9]['"][\S]/;

```
function getValue()  {
    return document.getElementById("myinput").value;
}

function test() {
    alert(regex.test(getValue()));
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uf8z1eh3/